# Preact app using react router doesn't render routes in sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, react-router, react-router-dom, preact

I have a Preact app using react router, and trying to run it from a sub folder on my shared hosting provider.

When I load the site, neither the first route or any subsequent routes load. Only the main page and navigation load (and change the url on click).

I tried using `basename="/company"` on `<Router basename="/company"/>`, but this doesn't seem to make a difference

I also created a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /company
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IFModule>
```

But can't get the routes to load. I see in the console that they're trying to load from the root of the server (`domain.com/route-Colors.chunk.123abc.js)`, rather than the folder they're in (`domain.com/company/route-Colors.chunk.123abc.js)`.

What am I missing in order to allow Preact and react router to load the initial view and all subsequent routes from a sub folder on my shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a `preact-cli` app, though you haven't said.

This is what Webpack's `publicPath` does. You'll need to configure it in your config file.

preact.config.js

```js
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
    if (env.production) {
        config.output.publicPath = 'https://example.com/company';
    }
}
```

Normally the public path is `/`, so it tries to load all assets from the root directory.

Comment: This was the directory rewrite I needed for the top level files, thank you!!! However, I have two other related issues: 

I have a few pages with sub route such as `<Route exact path={["/colors", "/colors/:path"]} component={Colors}/>`, but they don't load when selected from a tab on the `/colors` page. How can I configure the subroutes to load? 

Also, when I reload the page from any of the routes except for the first one, the site doesn't load the project files.

What else do I need to add for the above issues to be resolved?